# Show result with atleast two matching values and one matching is set to primary

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do you display results where the person have 2 matching values with Color blue and red and person have **primary of blue is set to 1 and red to 0**

```
PersonList  primary   color
person1       1       blue
person1       0       red
person2       1       blue       
person3       1       red
person3       0       blue
person4       1       blue
person4       0       red
person4       1       blue
```

Result Should Display Person1 and Person 4

NOTE: As long as blue its primary is set to 1 and red set to 0.

So far this is the my query from the result above

```
Select * person p Inner Join COLOR c ON p.person_colorid = c.person_colorid
```

I have tried this query but I know there is wrong with this. Which will display red with primary as 1 and also blue as 1

Person table contains [personList],[person_colorid] and [is_primary] while color table contains [color] and [person_colorid]

```
Select * person p Inner Join COLOR 
c ON p.person_colorid = c.person_colorid where c.color IN (blue,red) AND p.primary = 1
```

Comment: GROUP BY, or self join.

Comment: which rdbms ????

Comment: sql server 2014

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression to check the conditions that the `PersonList` which matching both the conditions.

**Query**

```
select t.[PersonList] from(
    select [PersonList],
    sum(case when [color] = 'red' and [primary] = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as [red],
    sum(case when [color] = 'blue' and [primary] = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as [blue]
   from [your_table_name]
   group by [PersonList]
)t
where t.[red] > 0 and t.[blue] > 0;
```